# Backlinks and Cross-Domain Canonical

Tags: seo, canonical-url, backlinks

I have two domains let say a.com and b.com

I'm doin SEO for a.com and got many quality backlinks to it, but now I want to change domain to b.com and I'm using cross-domain canonical so a.com still can be accessed without redirect 301.

The question is, will my backlinks from a.com transfer the values to the b.com like redirect?

Answer (score 1):

When changing domain names there are more important signals than backlinks for preserving your SEO. The only way to change your domain name and preserve the SEO is to implement a 301 redirect from one to the other and also use the Google search console change of address tool.

The change of address tool is the only method of preserving your SEO when changing domain and it doesn't support canonical URLs it only supports redirects. You should implement redirects and use the tool and forget trying to use canonical to two from one domain name to another.